# Eigenvector expansion?

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Does anyone know what they mean by Eigenvector expansion of $u_0$? I am at a complete loss on that part of the problem. The coding part I understood :)

[image]

Comment: This is explained in linear algebra books. Do you know what a basis is? How about what an eigenvector is?

Comment: Ya I do understand those ideas... I guess I just don't know how to put it together for the question. I can find the basis and eigenvectors of the matrix, but I am not sure what to do from there. I was reading this article. Is this what I am supposed to do do you think? http://www.math.ucla.edu/~anderson/135b.2.05w/EigenfunctionExpansion/EigenVectorExpansion.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're considering a finite-difference based numerical method, with a uniform grid $0=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_{N-1}<x_n=1$, then $u^0 = [u(x_1,0), ~ u(x_2,0), ~ \ldots, ~ u(x_{N-1},0)]^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{N-1}$.

Let $C = I - \beta k D_+ D_-$.  (Then $u^{n+1} = C u^n$, or equivalently $u^n = C^n u^0$.)

Suppose $C$ is diagonalizable, with eigenpairs $(\lambda_j, \boldsymbol\xi_j)$ ($j=1,2,\ldots,N-1$).  The hint -- which asks you to "expand $u^0$ in terms of the eigenvectors of $C$" -- is asking you to compute the coefficients $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_{N-1}$ satisfying $$u^0 = c_1 \boldsymbol\xi_1 + c_2 \boldsymbol\xi_2 + \cdots + c_{N-1} \boldsymbol\xi_{N-1}.$$